# Is it possible to describe the geometric mean of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: kinetic-theory

This may be a more appropriate question for the Mathematics stack exchange, if so forgive its extraneousness. We know the expected value of the distribution, analogous to the weighted arithmetic mean of the continuous random variable. $$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} v f(v) dv$$ We also know the geometric mean of numbers (not weighted) can be expressed as $$\exp[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \ln(X_i)]$$ Maybe a conection could be found with these pieces of maths but I can't find any obvious ones. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are going with this, but the arithmetic and geometric mean are not the same in the general case.
The geometrix mean is the $n_{th}$ square root of the product of the Xi for discrete values (that is what your formula says), while you gave an continuum expression for the arithmetic mean. Maybe you should write down the arithmetic mean for discrete values.

See also 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: I know what it is, I want to find it for the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution (a continuum expression for the geometric mean)